# How to prove $\gcd(a^m-b^m,a^n-b^n) = a^{\gcd(m,n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)} $?

Tags: number-theory

A problem taken from the exercises of *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik  is as follows:

> Prove that if $a\perp b$ and $a>b$ then
>      $$\gcd(a^m-b^m,a^n-b^n) = a^{\gcd(m,n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)},\quad 0\leq m<n.$$

(In the notation of the book, $a\perp b$ means that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, i.e. $\gcd(a,b)=1$.)

I can not prove this equation. Can you please help me to prove this formula?

Comment: Hint: Start by showing the indicated expression is a common divisor.  Then examine the respective quotients.

Comment: I've added the hypotheses on $a$ and $b$ that were stated in the problem.

Comment: What does 'a' is perpendicular to 'b' mean?

Comment: Alternatively, assuming $m>n$, show that if $d|a^m-b^m$ and $d|a^n-b^n$ then $d|a^{m-n}-b^{m-n}$. This lets you prove the theorem by induction.

Comment: what  does a⊥b mean ?

Comment: a⊥b means a is relatively prime with respect to b

Comment: @SultanAhmedSagor When you write a comment, please be specific. "yes I try to do that > But then ?? ". It doesn't mean anything, given that you've received at least two suggestions

Comment: a^n-b^n = (a^m-b^m) ( a^(n-m)b^0 + a^(n-2m)b^m + .............................. + a^(r)b^(n-m-r) ) + b^(m* floor(n/m) (a^r-B^r))  

Can I take any decision of gcd(a^n-b^n,a^m-b^m) from this  equations ?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exercise 4.38. There is a hint to use Euclid's algorithm that you forgot to reproduce. There is also an answer (p. 503) that reads

$a^n-b^n =(a^m-b^m)(a^{n-m}b^0+a^{n-2m}b^m+\cdots+a^{n\bmod m}b^{n-m-n\bmod m})+b^{m\lfloor n/m\rfloor}(a^{n\bmod m}-b^{n\bmod m})$

What this means is that the first step of Euclid's algorithm reduces $\gcd(a^n-b^n,a^m-b^m)$ to $\gcd(a^m-b^m,b^{m\lfloor n/m\rfloor}(a^{n\bmod m}-b^{n\bmod m}))$. But $b^{m\lfloor n/m\rfloor}$ is relatively prime to $a^n-b^n$ since it divides the second term and is relatively prime to the first term; therefore it will be relatively prime to the $\gcd$ that is being computed, and we might as well remove that factor from the second argument of the $\gcd$. All in all this gives
$$
  \gcd(a^n-b^n,a^m-b^m)
  =\gcd(a^m-b^m,a^{n\bmod m}-b^{n\bmod m}).
$$
Now iterating as in the Euclidean algorithm eventually gives
$$
\gcd(a^m-b^m,a^n-b^n) = a^{\gcd(m,n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)}.
$$

Comment: Many Many Thanks

Comment: I can not solve 24 no. problem of 4th chapter .Can you plz help me to solve it ?

Comment: Why don't you post it (with reference) as a separate question, explain what you tried and why the answer on page 502 is insufficient for you to get it? The one-question-per-question format works best on this site.

Answer (score 3):

**Outline of a proof:**

Let $d\mid a^n-b^n$ and $d\mid a^m-b^m$.

The "slick" solution is to show that if $mx+ny=\gcd(m,n)$, then since:

$$a^m\equiv b^m\pmod d$$

and

$$a^n\equiv b^n\pmod d$$

Then:

$$a^{(m,n)}=(a^m)^x (a^n)^y \equiv (b^m)^x(b^n)^y = b^{(m,n)}\pmod d$$

The only tricky part here is that you need to understand that we can invert $a$ and $b$ modulo $d$ since $a\perp b$ means that $d\perp a$ and $d\perp b$.  So, although $x$ or $y$ might be negative, you can work around this by taking care.

Comment: a^n-b^n = (a^m-b^m) ( a^(n-m)b^0 + a^(n-2m)b^m + .............................. + a^(r)b^(n-m-r) ) + b^(m* floor(n/m) (a^r-B^r)) Can I take any decision of gcd(a^n-b^n,a^m-b^m) from this equations ?

Comment: I understand the solution . Many Many Thanks .