# greater divior polynomials

Tags: divisor-sum

Let $n,m$ be positive integers and $d = \gcd(n,m). $

Prove that $\gcd(x^{n} -1 ,x^{m} -1) = x^{d} -1$.

Is this correct?

Bezout : integers $r,s$:  $\quad r(x^{n} -1) + s(x^{m} -1) = rx^{n} +sx^{m} - (r+s) =  x^{d} -1$

Comment: $r, s$ are polynomials with integer/rational coefficients in this context.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262130/how-to-prove-gcdam-bm-an-bn-a-gcdm-n-b-gcdm-n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1