# Let $r$ be the remainder of $a$ when dividing by $b$. Prove: $2^r -1$ is the remainder of $2^a -1$ when dividing by $2^b -1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having trouble proving this question. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It says dividing by $2^b -$1

Comment: u can start by dividend = divisor*quotient + remainder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove $\gcd(a^m-b^m,a^n-b^n) = a^{\gcd(m,n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262130/how-to-prove-gcdam-bm-an-bn-a-gcdm-n-b-gcdm-n)

Answer (score 1):

Let $b\equiv r\bmod a$. This implies $a \mid b-r$ and $r<a$. So $2^a-1\mid 2^{b-r}-1$ and hence $2^a-1\mid(2^{b}-1)-(2^r-1)$. Now observe $2^r-1<2^a-1$  and hence the remainder is $2^r-1$.

Comment: How do you get from $2^(b-r) -$1 to  ($2^b - $1) - ($2^r - $1). These are not the same right?

Comment: a=r mod b because we are dividing by b and not a

Comment: @Kath $(2^{b}-1)-(2^r-1)=2^r(2^{b-r}-1)$

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution sorry I don't know how to write in latex I am new I hope that my solution is helpful : [image]