# Elemantary number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let's $v$ the smallest positive integer > 1 for which $2 ^ {v} - 1$ divisible by $p$.
Prove that $2 ^ {m} - 1$ ($m > v$) divisible by $p$ then and only then $v$ divide $m$?

There is a hint that enough to divide $m$ into $v$ with the remainder, but it gives me nothing.

Comment: See my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3117286/543867

Comment: @Dbchatto67 great! Thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome @Евгений Кондратенко.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 can you mark it as duplicate or I should close it?

Comment: It is better to close this question to avoid future downvotes.

Comment: Please use descriptive titles. “Elementary number theory” (misspelled because somebody already used the insipid title elsewhere) does not help find the question later nor does it help tell readers what this is about.

Answer (score 0):

$m>v$

If $m=k.v$, then we have:

$2^m-1=[(2^v)^k-1]=(2^v-1)[(2^v)^{k-1}+(2^v)^{k-2}+ . . . +1]$

$p|2^v-1$  ⇒ $p|2^m-1$